# Batch script How to add space on a numerical variable

Tags: batch-file

First of approaches, excuse me if I do not express myself well in English.

I'm debutante in batch and I need help to make a script

I articles.txt retrieves a document in which there are many lines.
some lines of my document

> ```
> "T0047" ;"Tuyau 1km";"Marque2";"jardinage";"75 000";"promo"
> "T00747";"Tuyau 1m";Marque2";"jardinage";"30 000";"promo"
> ```

First, I have to remove the quotation marks in the file.
It is done with:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (articles.txt) do (
        set a=%%a
        set a=!a:"=!
        echo !a!
    echo !a! >>resultat.txt
)
```

the result

> ```
> T0047 ;Tuyau 1km;Marque2;jardinage;75 000;promo
> T00747;Tuyau 1m;Marque2;jardinage;30 000;promo
> ```

Then I have to perform a multiplication on a column.
For this, I have the problem that if the space is not so mutiplication realize I made a script that removes spaces.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=; tokens=1-8" %%a in (resultat.txt) do (
        set a=%%e
    set a=!a: =!
        echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!a!;%%f;%%g;%%h
    echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!a!;%%f;%%g;%%h >>resultat2.txt
)
```

the result

> ```
> T0047 ;Tuyau 1km;Marque2;jardinage;75000;promo
> T00747;Tuyau 1m;Marque2;jardinage;30000;promo
> ```

Then I made my multiplication.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=; tokens=1-8" %%a in (resultat2.txt) do (
        set a=%%e
        :: set /a a=!a!/0.6
         set /a a=!a!*16666/10000
    echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!a!;%%f;%%g;%%h
    echo  %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!a!;%%f;%%g;%%h >>resultat3.txt
)
```

the result

```
T0047 ;Tuyau 1km;Marque2;jardinage;124995;promo
T00747;Tuyau 1m;Marque2;jardinage;49998;promo
```

Now, i add some text just after the first colomn

```
set champ2=MAGASIN_1;T
for /F "delims=; tokens=1,*" %%a in (resultat3.txt) do (
        echo %%a;%champ2%;%%b
        echo %%a;%champ2%;%%b >>resultat_final.txt
)
```

The actual result is:

> ```
> T0047 ;MAGASIN_1;T;Tuyau 1km;Marque2;jardinage;124995;promo
> T00747;MAGASIN_1;T;Tuyau 1m;Marque2;jardinage;49998;promo
> ```

Now I would add a space so that the figure is more readable.

> ```
> T0047 ;MAGASIN_1;T;Tuyau 1km;Marque2;jardinage;124 995;promo
> T00747;MAGASIN_1;T;Tuyau 1m;Marque2;jardinage;49 998;promo
> ```

Comment: In your input document (`articles.txt`), there is a space after `"T0047"` (first line), and there is the opening `"` missing at `Marque2"` (second line) -- are these typos herein, or does the file really look like this?

Comment: Yes, the document look like that. Il is  It is created automatically every day, but it must be formatted before I realized the insertion in the database

Comment: I just recognised that your given result files (`resultat?.txt`) do not comply with the original, or feeding your original file `articles.txt` into the code portions you posted will never lead to the results you posted; so please clarify! it would also help a lot if you state the file names of the sample files (which of course should then fit to the code snippets)...

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in (articles.txt) do (
   set "a=%%A"
   set a=!a:"=!
   for /F "delims=; tokens=1-8" %%a in ("!a!") do (
      set /A "g1=%%g*16666/10000"
      set "g2="
      for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do if defined g1 (
         set "g2= !g1:~-3!!g2!"
         set "g1=!g1:~0,-3!
      )
      echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%%f;!g2:~1!;%%h
      echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%%f;!g2:~1!;%%h >> result.txt
   )
)
```

articles.txt:

```
"T0047" ;"MAGASIN_1";"T";"Tuyau 1km";"Marque2";"jardinage";"75000";"promo"
"T00747";"MAGASIN_1";"T";"Tuyau 1m";Marque2";"jardinage";"30000";"promo"
```

result.txt:

```
T0047 ;MAGASIN_1;T;Tuyau 1km;Marque2;jardinage;124 995;promo 
T00747;MAGASIN_1;T;Tuyau 1m;Marque2;jardinage;49 998;promo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond only to the multiplication section.

I can see nothing in your code that can possibly generte the two extra columns `;MAGASIN_1;T`and consequently, the target field `75000` and `30000` are in `%%g`, not `%%e`.

Comment : Do not use the "broken label" comment form `::comment` within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)` because it can terminate the block prematurely. Always use `rem` with a block.

So - modified code working on `%%g`

```
set a=%%g
rem set /a a=!a!/0.6
REM set /a a=!a!*16666/10000
set /a a=!a!*10/6
SET "a= !a:~-9,-6! !a:~-6,-3! !a:~-3!"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%q IN ("!a!") DO SET "a=%%q"
echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%%f;!a!;%%h
```

Reason: Batch has a signed-32-bit limit, so if the source field is >~120000 then your calculation will generate a negative number (try 130000 for example) The revised calculation is more accurate and since intermediate results are less likely to exceed 2**31 can cope with larger values in the `%%g` field.

The `set` following the calculation changes the numeric value in `a` to

> <kbd>space</kbd>(millions)<kbd>space</kbd>(thousands)<kbd>space</kbd>(units)

(The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".)

The `for /f "tokens=*"...` statement simply removes leading spaces from the value of `a`.

---

With the explanatin of the two additional columns, This revision should solve the "add-spaces" problem:

```
set a=%%e
rem set /a a=!a!/0.6
REM set /a a=!a!*16666/10000
set /a a=!a!*10/6
SET "a= !a:~-9,-6! !a:~-6,-3! !a:~-3!"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%q IN ("!a!") DO SET "a=%%q"
echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;!a!;%%f;%%g;%%h
```

however, if you want to skip the last step (insertion of 2 extra fields) then insert this line before the `for` line in the "multiplication" batch

```
set champ2=MAGASIN_1;T
```

and change the `echo` line in that batch to

```
echo %%a;%champ2%;%%b;%%c;%%d;!a!;%%f;%%g;%%h
```

Comment: Magoo, i let more information on the top of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is good. Some tips:

Don't divide by a power of 10. Instead, remove the fractional part if you don't want it. Use *= . And to get the space in the number:

```
@echo off

set x=75000
set /a x *= 16666
set x=%x:~0,-4%
echo %x:~0,-3% %x:~-3%
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a semicolon-delimited list of values where each item is enclosed within quotation marks, I would go for a standard `for` to get the items of each line and remove the enclosing quotation marks. The great advantage of this method is that it really cares about the quotation marks, so the list items may even contain semicolons on their own. The only disadvantage is that question marks and asterisks are not allowed in any of the list items:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Redirect all data to output file "resultat.txt" at once:
> "resultat.txt" (
    rem Loop through all (non-empty) lines of input file "articles.txt":
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("articles.txt") do (
        rem Reset list collector and loop index:
        set "LIST="
        set /A "INDEX=0"
        rem Loop through the list items of the current line:
        for %%I in (%%L) do (
            rem Apply current list item with `""` removed, increment loop index:
            set "ITEM=%%~I"
            set /A "INDEX+=1"
            rem Do numeric calculation for a certain list item:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if !INDEX! EQU 5 (
                rem Convert item to a number, avoid error messages:
                2> nul set /A "CALC=!ITEM!"
                rem Do calculation with rounding (for negative and positive numbers):
                if !CALC! LSS 0 (
                    set /A "CALC=(!CALC!*10-6/2)/6"
                ) else (
                    set /A "CALC=(!CALC!*10+6/2)/6"
                )
                rem Insert thousands separators (space) between every third digit:
                set "CALC=!CALC:~-12,-9! !CALC:~-9,-6! !CALC:~-6,-3! !CALC:~-3!"
                for /F "tokens=*" %%N in ("!CALC!") do (
                    set "ITEM=%%N"
                )
            )
            rem Append separator (semicolon) and current item to list:
            for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%S in ("!LIST!;!ITEM!") do (
                endlocal
                set "LIST=%%S"
            )
        )
        rem Return built list, remove superfluous leading separator (`;`):
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LIST:~1!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

The calculation herein incorporates rounding to the nearest integer, which works even for negative input numbers.

The newly generated list is stored into the new file `resultat.txt`.